# Updating custom cursor in java swing window

Tags: java, swing, window, custom-cursor

I want to set custom cursor in my java swing app, and then edit it.

I set a custom cusrsor after showing window (in "Window" class).
Later in code (in the other class), I want to chainge it again, so i call this `updateCursor()` funcion (in "Window" class again), and it and it won't work. There is no errors or warnings, but the cursor isn't changing - just stays the same. I tried, and I can't find answer anywhere. I appreciate any help.

This is full code - **Window.java**:

```java
import MainMenu;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Window {
    public static final int WIDTH = 817, HEIGHT = 640;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");

    public void open() {
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH - 33, HEIGHT - 25);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.requestFocus();
        frame.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);

        frame.addKeyListener(new InputManager());
        frame.addMouseListener(new InputManager());
        frame.add(new MainMenu());
        frame.add(new Game());

        loadCursors();

        updateCursor(0);
    }

    public static final int NORMAL = 0, ACTIVE = 1, INACTIVE = 2;

    Cursor cursor_normal, cursor_active, cursor_inactive;

    public void loadCursors() {
        try {
            cursor_normal = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(ImageIO.read(new File(new SpritesManager().cursor_normal)), new Point(0, 0), "custom cursor (normal)");
            cursor_active = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(ImageIO.read(new File(new SpritesManager().cursor_active)), new Point(0, 0), "custom cursor (active)");
            cursor_inactive = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(ImageIO.read(new File(new SpritesManager().cursor_inactive)), new Point(0, 0), "custom cursor (inactive)");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void updateCursor(int cursorType) {
        switch (cursorType) {
            case NORMAL -> frame.setCursor(cursor_normal);
            case ACTIVE -> frame.setCursor(cursor_active);
            case INACTIVE -> frame.setCursor(cursor_inactive);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainMenu.java**:

```java
import Window;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class MainMenu extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // testing
        new Window().updateCursor(Window.ACTIVE);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm new, and I started learning like 3 months ago, and switch apparently works in that way (above java 14) https://betterprogramming.pub/a-look-at-the-new-switch-expressions-in-java-14-ed209c802ba0 Anyway, in standard way, it won't work to...

Comment: You are right about the new switch syntax.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what "*won't work*" means in your case. Any errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: How can you prove that the call to `updateCursor()` actually happened?

Comment: @PM77-1 I tested it with `System.out.println();` - the method call and the switch works fine.

Comment: My last try: Have you by any chance declared `frame` in your other class?

Comment: @PM77-1 No, only in `Window` class. I also added `frame.add(new Painter());` and `frame.addKeyListener(new InputManager());` to the code later, but I thing thats not a problem.

Comment: It’s possible that the cursor is defined only for the component it’s set on - so when you add a new component to the frame, it’s that component’s cursor which is been applied, not the frame - I’d consider either moving the logic to the top level component or researching the glassPane

Comment: @MadProgrammer The problem is i can't update the cursor. It works, when I use `updateCursor` function for the first time. If I understood you correctly, it's not going to help. Or, can you give me a example? Sorry, I'm new here... :)

Comment: I understand your problem, but, your updating the cursor for the `JFrame` component, but a `JFrame` is a compound component (there are a number of components on top of it), plus what ever you place on it - all of these components have their own "cursor" settings.  From the JavaDocs *" This cursor image is displayed when the contains method for this component returns true for the current cursor location"* - This would suggest that the component which the mouse is over is actually determining the cursor state

Comment: I stand corrected, after some testing, it doesn’t seem to matter, so long as the component is visible on the frame, which suggests that the issue is somewhere in the code you’re not sharing

Comment: @MadProgrammer I updated the code. It may not be super clean, but like I said, I'm new here, and I'm learning java. By the way, I'm starting to think, that maybe my it's something wrong with my computer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do ...

```
new Window().updateCursor(Window.ACTIVE);
```

and magically expect the other instance of `Window` to be updated, in fact, you don't need to do this at all.

This is going to create another instance/copy of `Window`, which is not present on the screen and it will have no effect on the instance which is been displayed.

You could call `setCursor` directly on the instance `MainMenu`.

Now, if you want to "centralise" the functionality, I would start by creating a "manager" class, for example...

```
public class CursorManager {

    public enum CusorType {
        NORMAL, ACTIVE, INACTIVE;
    }

    private Cursor cursorNormal, cursorActive, cursorInactive;

    public CursorManager() throws IOException {
        cursorNormal = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(ImageIO.read(new File(new SpritesManager().cursor_normal)), new Point(0, 0), "custom cursor (normal)");
        cursorActive = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(ImageIO.read(new File(new SpritesManager().cursor_active)), new Point(0, 0), "custom cursor (active)");
        cursorInactive = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(ImageIO.read(new File(new SpritesManager().cursor_inactive)), new Point(0, 0), "custom cursor (inactive)");
    }

    public void setCursor(CusorType cursorType, Component comp) {
        switch (cursorType) {
            case NORMAL ->
                comp.setCursor(cursorNormal);
            case ACTIVE ->
                comp.setCursor(cursorActive);
            case INACTIVE ->
                comp.setCursor(cursorInactive);
        }
    }
}
```

I would then create this instance of the manager during the initialisation phase of your code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                CursorManager cursorManager = new CursorManager();
                //.. Every thing else...
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And then pass this instance to every class that might need it...

```
// You'll need to update Window to accept this parameter
new Window(cursorManager).open();
```

And...

```
public class MainMenu extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    private CursorManager cursorManager;
    
    private MainMenu(CursorManager cursorManager) {
        this.cursorManager = cursorManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // testing
        cursorManager.setCursor(CursorManager.CusorType.ACTIVE, this);
    }

    //...
}
```

This is commonly known as "dependency injection" and is VERY powerful

## Feedback

Just as a side note, if I was doing something like this, it would be very different, but I tried to keep it simple.

- We're generally discouraged from extending from top level containers like `JFrame`, as stated, `JFrame` is not a simple component and you're not actually adding any new functionality to the class and in the process, locking yourself into a single use, there by reducing re-usability.  Better to start with a `JPanel` as your base component and simply create an instance of `JFrame` or `JDialog or what ever top level container you want to use, when you need it
- `KeyListener` is a poor choice for monitoring keyboard input (seriously, just do a search for "my key listener won't work".  Instead, take a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Thanks, it works now! But I have only one last question (it may be dumb, but I'm interested) - Why in `try` (`main`), did you use `Logger.log()` instead of just `System.out.println(ex)`?

Comment: @Adamm The logging system is very flexible, apart from been able to give you information about the class/file and line of the log message, you can also log it to a file our other output source

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of your Window class in your keyPressed(..) method, therefore your cursor update does not work:

> new Window().updateCursor(Window.ACTIVE);

You need to pass your existing Window instance to your MainMenu class and call this instance.

Here's a working example:

**Main App**:

```
public class MyApp extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MyApp app = new MyApp();
                app.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private MyApp() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 600);

        // Create cursors
        Cursor c1 = Util.getCursor("c1.png");
        Cursor c2 = Util.getCursor("c2.png");

        setCursor(c1);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Change to Cursor1");
        button1.setActionCommand("c1");
        button1.addActionListener(new MyActionListener(this));

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Change to Cursor2");
        button2.setActionCommand("c2");
        button2.addActionListener(new MyActionListener(this));

        add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(button2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

}
```

**ActionListener** (handles the button clicks):

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame jFrame;

    public MyActionListener(JFrame jFrame) {
        this.jFrame = jFrame;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getActionCommand()){
            case "c1":
                jFrame.setCursor(Util.getCursor("c1.png"));
                System.out.println("switch to c1");
                break;
            case "c2":
                jFrame.setCursor(Util.getCursor("c2.png"));
                System.out.println("switch to c2");
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

**Util** (read cursor image):

```
public class Util {
    public static Cursor getCursor(String fileName) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(Util.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(img, new Point(0, 0), fileName);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your example works, but when I tried to implement it to my code, there is no result (default windows cursor). I even copied it to difrent project, and it still the same.

Comment: I updated my answer. The problem is that in MainMenu.java, you create a new Window instance instead of using the existing instance.